# How to test SSLSessionCacheTimeout

Tags: java, ssl, https

How can i configure and test SSLSessionCacheTimeout  value?
How it is differs from http keep alive timeout?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: Which server you are referring to?

Comment: @Santosh He isn't referring to a server at all.

Answer (score 6):

> How can i configure and test SSLSessionCacheTimeout value?

You can configure it via [SSLSocket.getSession().getSessionContext().setSessionTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html#setSessionTimeout%28int%29).

You can test it by running your client with `-Djavax.net.debug-ssl,handshake`, creating an `SSLSocket` connected to your server, sleeping for longer than the timeout, and creating a second `SSLSocket` connected to the same server. You can see from the debug output whether the same session has been resumed for the second connection, or a new session started.

> How it is differs from http keep alive timeout?

Questions like this are basically meaningless. It is not even slightly the same, and it isn't the same as TCP keepalive either. It is a timeout on the session key materials and identity authentication derived from an SSL handshake, which are collectively called an SSL session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to configure in tomcat server by modifying the conf file. Not through program. I am talking about http keepalive not tcp. This also making persistent connection without exchanging request message

Comment: @user1345697 (a) You can't configure it in Tomcat by modifying configuration files; (b) SSL sessions don't make persistent connections, they do what I said in my last paragraph, across connections. It beats me competely why you would want to use a feature when you don't know what it does and you don't know how to configure it.